# dealing with multiple charset in python 3

Tags: python, character-encoding, python-3.3

I'm using python 3.3.0 in Windows 8.

```
requrl = urllib.request.Request(url) 

response = urllib.request.urlopen(requrl)

source = response.read()

source = source.decode('utf-8')
```

It will work fine if the websites have `utf-8` charset but what if it has `iso-8859-1` or any other `charset`. Means I may have different website url with different charset.
So, how to deal with multiple charset?

Now let me tell you my efforts when I tried to resolve this issue like:

```
    b1 = b'charset=iso-8859-1'
    b1 = b1.decode('iso-8859-1')

    if b1 in source:
            source = source.decode('iso-8859-1')
```

It gave me an error like `TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API`
So, I'm assuming that it's considering b1 as string! and this is not the correct way! :(

Please, don't say that manually change charset in the source code or have you read python docs!
I have already tried to put my head into python 3 docs but still have no luck or I may not be picking up correct modules/contents to read!

Comment: By removing the part of your question, you render my answer a rambling of a madman.

Answer (score 5):

In Python 3, a `str` is actually a sequence of unicode characters (equivalent to `u'mystring'` syntax in Python 2). What you get back from `response.read()` is a byte string (a sequence of bytes).

The reason your `b1 in source` fails is you are trying to find a *unicode character sequence* inside a *byte string*. This makes no sense, so it fails. If you take out the line `b1.decode('iso-8859-1')`, it should work because you are now comparing two byte sequences.

**Now back to your real underlying issue.** To support multiple charsets, you need to determine the character set so you cn decode it to a Unicode string. This is tricky to do. Normally you can examine the `Content-Type` header of the response. (See the rules below.)  However, *so many websites declare the wrong encoding in the header* that we have had to develop other [complicated encoding sniffing rules for html](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/parsing.html#determining-the-character-encoding). Please read that link so you realize what a difficult problem this is!

I recommend you either:

1. Use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library instead of urllib, because it automatically takes care of most unicode conversions properly. (It's also much easier to use.) If conversion to unicode at this layer fails:
2. Try to pass the bytes directly to an underlying library you are using (e.g. `lxml` or `html5lib`) and let them deal with determining the encoding. They often implement the right charset-sniffing algorithms for the document type.

If neither of these work, you can get more aggressive and use libraries like [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) to detect the encoding, but in my experience people who serve their web pages this incorrectly are so incompetent that they produce mixed-encoding documents, so you will end up with garbage characters no matter what you do!

Here are the rules for interpreting the charset declared in a `content-type` header.

1. With no explicit charset declared:

   1. text/* (e.g., text/html) is in ASCII.
   2. application/* (e.g. application/json, application/xhtml+xml) is utf-8.
2. With an explicit charset declared:

   1. if type is text/html and charset is iso-8859-1, it's actually win-1252 (==CP1252)
   2. otherwise use the charset declared.

(Note that the html5 spec willfully violates the w3c specs by looking for UTF8 and UTF16 byte markers *in preference to* the Content-Type header. Please read that encoding detection algorithm link and see why we can't have nice things...)

Comment: Interesting presets for application/*. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: I'd say `application/*` in many cases isn't `utf8`, as shown by a quick [grep from /etc/apache2/magic](http://pastebin.com/XMAStN2b)

Answer (score 2):

The big problem here is that in many cases you can't be sure about the encoding of a webpage, even if it defines a charset. I've seen enough pages declaring one charset but acutally being in another, or having a different charsets in their Content-Type header then in their meta-tag or xml declaration.

In such cases [`chardet`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet2) can be helpful.

Comment: Hmn, It can be big issue if they are doing like that. I can understand it well. So, I must use that chardet or is there any way in python to detect/fetch charset automatically? Anyway, which charsets are mostly used in websites? otherwise my script will be limited to utf-8 encoding only! :(

Comment: chardet tries to determine the charset of a text by looking at known character sequences and applying different heuristics, so it can help you if the page doesn't declare a charset or a wrong one, of course you could write your own logic to detect the charset in such cases, but why reinvent the wheel (requests for example also uses chardet). Of course in most cases the charset declared by the page is the right one, but having a fallback method to determine the charset can't hurt. For info about the most used charsets look [here](http://trends.builtwith.com/encoding)

Comment: OMG, After watching at that link, I must say, I will try to be with utf-8 or iso-8859-1

Answer (score 1):

You're checking whether `str` bytes contained within `bytes` object:

```
>>> 'df' in b'df'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#107>", line 1, in <module>
    'df' in b'df'
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

So, yes, it considers `b1` a `str`, because you've decoded `bytes` object into a `str` object with the certain encoding. Instead, you should check against original value of `b1`. It's not clear why you do `.decode` on it.

Comment: Hey, you may be right but that's not the my actual question. That I have tried to get result. But you made me clear about it that what it actually do and why it gives an error.
My question is regarding support of diff. charset

Comment: @magneto: and what is your question?

Comment: I have edited my above comment. Now, you got my que. regarding charset??? otherwise give me your email-id, so we can have debate on this. :) It's really a big ques. in python 3 if I'm not wrong!

Comment: @magneto: may be you could try [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) package? they advertise unicode response bodies. This seems what you want. Otherwise detecting charset and decoding it similarly to what you've done could be the way forward.

Comment: Hmn, I didn't get your first point but how to do/implement that in python 3 if I want to go for second option that detecting charset...

Comment: @magneto: what do you not get? which first point? Get requests (link was provided), install it and use it. You are already detecting charsets, there are many issues there though. Give requests a try.

Comment: Hey, why I have removed it because it's not working. It was just my try to get it but I failed! And I was having no intention to make your answer meaningless. And I don't want to use any external packages. I want to make it by python 3 only. So, let me again ask do you know how to resolve the issue when we have multiple charset to look for, otherwise give me your email-id, I will send you my script. So, you can have better idea. Anyway, thanks for your reply bro.

Comment: @magneto: If it were working, it wouldn't be a question. Anyway, the simplest way is what you were doing: checking what charset is supplied (if any, might be missing) and trying to decode the page in that encoding (if it's available in python). Again, it's an error-prone approach and you'd be better off using existing library. The point of StackOverflow is that we're having a public discussion, so that other might find it and learn from it. It wasn't supposed to be a discussion, of course, more of a Q'n'A, but I don't see what else could be said, you already now how to check charset and decode

Comment: Yup, that's why I respect StackOverflow. But what you are saying is not an answer of my question. Yup, that's what I want to do. Check which charset and decode the contents into that encoding. And Is it allow to put pastebin.com link of my code here? So, you will be having more clarity of my question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [HTML standard, Parsing HTML documents, Determine character set](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/parsing.html#determining-the-character-encoding) (HTML5 is sufficient for our purposes).

There is an algorithm to take. For *your* purpose boils down to the following:

1. Check for identifying sequences for UTF-16 or UTF-8 (see provided link)
2. Use the character set supplied by HTTP (via the [Content-Type header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.17))
3. Apply the algorithm described a little later in [Prescan a byte-stream to determine its encoding](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/parsing.html#prescan-a-byte-stream-to-determine-its-encoding). This is basically searching for "charset=" in the document and extracting the value.